# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_40 is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 58)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on a dataset about student performance in a course, and I want to predict student level (low, mid, high) according to their previous year's marks. I'm using a CNN for this purpose, but when I build and fit the model I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_40 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 58)
```

This is the code:

```
#reshaping data
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1])) 

#checking the shape after reshaping
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

#normalizing the pixel values
X_train=X_train/255
X_test=X_test/255

#defining model
model=Sequential()

#adding convolution layer
model.add(Conv1D(32,3, activation='relu',input_shape=(28,1)))

#adding pooling layer
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))

#adding fully connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))

#adding output layer
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

#compiling the model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

#fitting the model
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10)
```

This is the output:

```
Model: "sequential_40"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_23 (Conv1D)           (None, 9, 32)             128       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_19 (MaxPooling (None, 4, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_15 (Flatten)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_30 (Dense)             (None, 100)               12900     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_31 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1010      
=================================================================
Total params: 14,038
Trainable params: 14,038
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: The input_shape given to the first conv has to match to the shape of your dataset, why did you set it to (28,1) if the dataset has 58 features?

Comment: What is the output of these two lines : `print(X_train.shape)
, print(X_test.shape)`

Comment: thank you its work after i change the input to  58

Answer (score 0):

you should reshape your training data as below:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_test  = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
```

by doing this you just add a dimension to the inputs. Then your input shape will be like (None, X_train.shape[1], 1).